# Calculate mean number of particles of time evolution coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, lie-algebra, eigenvalue

[image]

I seem to be missing some identities. I know you need to calculate `P_n = |<n|alpha_t>|^2`
and mean number of particles is the infinite sum of nP_n. However I can't get to a stage where I apply the hint

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: This is a sketch of a brute-force solution.  [udrv](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/87624/udrv)'s explanation is way cooler.  We start from $|\alpha\rangle = e^{-\frac12|\alpha|^2}e^{\alpha\hat a^\dagger}|0\rangle$.  Expanding this yields $|\alpha\rangle = e^{-\frac12|\alpha|^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(\alpha \hat a^\dagger)^n}{n!}|0\rangle=e^{-\frac12|\alpha|^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle$.

Comment: Since $\hat H|n\rangle = n\hbar \omega|n\rangle$, we have $e^{-i\hat H t/\hbar}|n\rangle = e^{i n \omega t}|n\rangle$.  So $e^{-i\hat H t/\hbar}|\alpha\rangle = e^{-\frac12|\alpha|^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{i n \omega t}\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}|n\rangle = |e^{i\omega t} \alpha\rangle$, which differs from $|\alpha\rangle$ only by a phase $\omega t$. The number of particles is given by $\langle n\rangle = \langle\alpha|\hat n|\alpha\rangle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n |\langle n | \alpha\rangle|^2$, which can be shown to be independent of the phase of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

The following does not need the hint, but gives an easy way to retrieve the exact evolved state and prove the conservation of the average number of particles.

The idea is to make use of the coherent state expression you had in a previous question. For $t=0$ let
$$
|\alpha(0)\rangle = e^{\alpha_0 \, \hat a^\dagger - \alpha^*_0 \, \hat a} |0\rangle.
$$
Use the Schroedinger equation to evolve the state for time $t>0$ and rewrite it as
$$
|\alpha(t)\rangle = e^{-i\omega t\;\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}}e^{\alpha_0 \, \hat a^\dagger - \alpha^*_0 \, \hat a} |0\rangle = \left( e^{-i\omega t\;\hat a^\dagger \hat a}e^{\alpha_0 \, \hat a^\dagger - \alpha^*_0 \, \hat a} e^{i\omega t\;\hat a^\dagger \hat a}\right) e^{-i\omega t\;\hat a^\dagger \hat a}|0\rangle = e^{\alpha_0 \, \hat a^\dagger(t) - \alpha^*_0 \, \hat a(t)}|0\rangle
$$
where 
$$
\hat a(t) = e^{-i\omega t\;\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}} \hat a e^{i\omega t\;\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a}}
$$ 
Note that $\hat a(t)$ looks very much like the Heisenberg evolved operator, but is actually defined as evolved backwards in time. There is nothing wrong in this, since we are not actually using the Heisenberg representation, but only a math artifice. The important thing is that $\hat a(t)$ and $\hat a^\dagger(t)$ admit nice closed expressions, which can be easily obtained by taking the time derivative on both sides and using the commutation relations. The result is  $\frac{d\hat a(t)}{dt} = -i\omega \hat a(t)$ and the solution reads simply 
$$
\hat a(t) = e^{-i\omega t}\hat a
$$
Taking this into the expression for $|\alpha(t)\rangle$ shows that it is a coherent state with $\alpha(t) = \alpha_0 e^{i\omega t}$. The conservation of the average number of particles follows thereof.